# Android 5.0.1 doesn't handling additional media buttons

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, media-button

when I use android 4.4.4 (Galaxy Nexus) minus button plays next song. plus button plays previous song. But android 5.0 (Nexus 4) no actions for these buttons. if android no longer support these buttons. I wan't to implement myself.

How can I receive key event from these media buttons?

I've tested these methods. But no luck.

```
AudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver
MediaSession.setCallback
```

and

```
<intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
</intent-filter>
```

[image http://cdn.shopclues.net/images/detailed/403/ForSAMSUNGGALAXYS3IIIS4I9300ForSAMSUNGGALAXYNoteN7000Note2N7100HANDSFREEHEADPHONES1_1365530097.jpg](http://cdn.shopclues.net/images/detailed/403/ForSAMSUNGGALAXYS3IIIS4I9300ForSAMSUNGGALAXYNoteN7000Note2N7100HANDSFREEHEADPHONES1_1365530097.jpg)

Comment: Possibly related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44144/how-to-make-volume-buttons-on-earphones-headphones-work-with-android, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/62761/change-action-of-headset-button?rq=1. Anyway, Android development is off-topic here.

Comment: Now I think it's related product vendor. Samsung phone works nice with samsung headphone. Nexus 4 is LG phone. Maybe I need lg standard headphone.

Comment: That's a possibility. Unfortunately I don't have Samsung earphone to test. Though, you might consider to update your question to ask if it's possible to use Samsung earphone on Nexus or other devices than Samsung. (But you need to remove that bit code, since development-related is off-topic here :)